# How to fix ‘Cannot read property 'params' of undefined’ error in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-props

I want to know whats wrong with my code every-time i got this MSG "Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" I want to pass a props from page to another, I've fetch multi API and from the second API i want to get some images to pass it on the other view. The first API working fine at ProfileHeader.JS but the second one with ProfileTabs.JS Iam facing some problems with it.

I'am not sure where is my problem - "sorry for my poor English"

My first view:

```
ProfileLanding.JS

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ProfileHeader from './ProfileHeader';
import ProfileTabs from './ProfileTabs';

function ProfileLanding({ match }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
        console.log(match);
    }, []);
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        image: {}
    });
    const [usergallery, setUsergallery] = useState({
        image: {}
    });
    const fetchUser = async () => {
        let [fetchUser, fetchUsergallery] = await Promise.all([
            fetch(
                `http://arabcdb.com/backstage/login/teamapibyid/${match.params.id}`
            ),
            fetch(
                `https://arabcdb.com/backstage/login/mediateamapiid/${match.params.id}`
            )
        ]);
        const userr = await fetchUser.json();
        setUser(userr);
        const usergalleryr = await fetchUsergallery.json();
        setUsergallery(usergalleryr);
    };
    return(
               <section className="col-md-9">
                   <ProfileHeader user={user} />
                   <ProfileTabs usergallery={usergallery} />
               </section>
    )
}
export default ProfileLanding;
```

and this is my second view:

```
ProfileTabs.JS

import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import './ProfileTabs.css'
class ProfileTabs extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
        console.log(props)
      }
      componentDidMount() {
         const test = this.props.match.params.id;
        fetch(`http://arabcdb.com/backstage/login/mediateamapiid/${test}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
      }
      render() {
        return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="gallery" id="gallery">
                       {
                           this.state.data.map(item => (
                            <div className="mb-3 pics animation all 2" key={item.id}><img className="img-fluid" src={"http://arabcdb.com/backstage/uploads/" + item.image} alt="Card cap" /></div>
                           ))
                       }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ProfileTabs;
```

[View Error MSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x5YH.png)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't actually have the match prop.

In your ProfileTabs.js file since you are using a class component you should wrap it in the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) HOC. Or if you prefer to use function components you can then use the [useparams](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/hooks.md#useparams) hook.

You can also pass the prop down from the ProfileLanding.js component.

Use the one that is easier for you.

Comment: may you send an example to understand it, sorry but iam new in react

Comment: Basically what I think is happening here is that you have the ProfileLanding as a Route component and that's why you have the match prop, but since that is not the case for the ProfileTabs you don't have it. So what we can do to get this prop is to use the withRouter HOC. To do this you have to add this import `import { withRouter } from "react-router";` and change how you export your component `export default withRouter(ProfileTabs);`.

Comment: done but how could i get my id only without user and how could i use it inside my API

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: i dont know after i put "withRouter" how to include it inside my api http://......./id

Comment: You need the withRouter only to wrap the ProfileTabs component as explained in my first comment. Looking at the code it seems like you are already including the id into the fetch path in the componentDidMount lifecycle.